# Metallic reverb from ceiling, only in 1 room

Tags: home-studio, reverb, room-treatment, issue, building

I just moved into a new house and I'm having an extremely strange sound issue with one of the rooms.

Everything within the room reverberates with a strong metallic sound that appears to originate from the center of the ceiling. It's bad enough that it's literally hard to have a conversation in the room, let alone listen to movies or music.

I've considered the following possibilities:

**1. The room is too empty.** The only thing on the walls is a pair of heavy drapes, and the only furniture a bed, 2 nightstands, and a console. *However,* the room next door (same size) has the exact same setup and no discernible reverb.

**2. The room is on an outside corner** where the cinderblock structure might be the issue. *However,* the room on the opposite corner does not have this issue and is, in fact, solid enough to be used as my studio.

**3. There might be something metal in the crawlspace above the ceiling.** If this were the case, it would only be in this room. I haven't been able to check because it's very difficult to get to.

Am I missing something? Where else could I look to diagnose this issue?

**Edits:**

- All rooms referenced are carpeted.
- The room in question is 12' x 10' with a 3' x 3' entry alcove. The second bedroom is of the exact same dimensions. The studio is a more irregular shape (which is why I selected it for a studio).

Comment: You could throw a heavy rug in the middle of the floor. Unless all your reference rooms are absolutely identical in size, this one just might have all the right dimensions for a nasty standing wave.

Comment: @Tetsujin Good to know that's possible. The rooms are not all perfectly identical, but they ARE carpeted. Will add that to the original post.

Comment: Hang the rug on one wall, then. Modern very square buildings are just horrible for acoustics. Basically, you have to find the main culprit & kill it. If the frequencies are high enough, you can effectively do that with some form of 'soft furnishing'. Concrete block is very 'spanky', plasterboard/drywall is very 'ringy' Neither are good.

Comment: Please give us the dimensions of the room. I'll bet it's square.

Comment: @KurtGibson added! The room is not QUITE square, but it's somewhat close? However the second bedroom is identical, just rotated 90°.

Comment: This is well known when you move into an empty house. Fill rooms with furniture and so on, and the problem will disappear.